# resize combobox component scroll bar flash cs5

Tags: flash, components, customization, flash-cs5

Is there a way i can re-size the scroll bar inside the combo box component? within flash CS5

Comment: which way do you wan to resize it?

Comment: increase the size horizontally (width) of the bar